# Recording FLAC audio in a Windows Store App

Tags: encoding, windows-store-apps, audio-recording, flac

I am writing a Windows Store App (Metro App) in which I need to be able to record sound in the FLAC format. From what I've seen in MS's info (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh452798.aspx), there are some predefined encoding profiles:

- AAC audio (M4A)
- MP3 audio
- Windows Media Audio (WMA)
- MP4 video (H.264 video plus AAC audio)
- Windows Media Video (WMV)

Of course not included is FLAC. I know next to nothing about encoding type stuff so I'd like some guidance here.

Can I somehow get a FLAC encoding profile in here somewhat easily?

OR

Should I just record and convert via a utility? (I need a fast turnaround time so I'd rather not use this method)

- If this is in fact the best way to do it, what would be a good utility that I could run from a store app environment?

Thanks for any help